# Depiction using gg_rain() in R

Tags: r

I would like to describe a graph using gg_rain. I inserted "boxplot.args.pos = list(width = .1, ggpp::position_dodgenudge(x = -20, 20))" to make the distance between violin plot and box plot, but when i changed the values, the plot didn't change.

Could you please tell me what to do?

```
set.seed(42) # the magic number
seed = 42

iris_subset <- iris[iris$Species %in% c('versicolor', 'virginica'),]

iris.long <- cbind(rbind(iris_subset, iris_subset, iris_subset), 
                   data.frame(time = c(rep("t1", dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep("t2", dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep("t3", dim(iris_subset)[1])),
                              id = c(rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]))))

# adding .5 and some noise to the versicolor species in t2
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"] + .5 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"]), sd = .2)
# adding .8 and some noise to the versicolor species in t3
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"] + .8 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"]), sd = .2)

# now we subtract -.2 and some noise to the virginica species
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"] - .2 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"]), sd = .2)

# now we subtract -.4 and some noise to the virginica species
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"] - .4 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"]), sd = .2)

iris.long$Sepal.Width <- round(iris.long$Sepal.Width, 1) # rounding Sepal.Width so t2 data is on the same resolution
iris.long$time <- factor(iris.long$time, levels = c('t1', 't2', 't3'))



ggplot(iris.long[iris.long$time %in% c('t1', 't2'),], aes(time, Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_rain(alpha = .5, rain.side = 'f2x2', id.long.var = "id",
            line.args.pos = rlang::list2(position = position_jitter(width = .04, height = 0, seed = seed)),
            boxplot.args.pos = list(width = .1, ggpp::position_dodgenudge(x = -20, 20))) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +
  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none')
#> Warning: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: alpha
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to move the violin if you want to increase the space between the boxes and the violin. The interface of `geom_rain` doesn't seem to allow an easy way to achieve this. The best I could come up with is overwriting the layer's position object.

First, we store the original plot:

```r
p <- ggplot(iris.long[iris.long$time %in% c('t1', 't2'),], 
       aes(time, Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_rain(alpha = .5, rain.side = 'f2x2', id.long.var = "id",
            line.args.pos = rlang::list2(position = position_jitter(width = .04, 
                                         height = 0, seed = seed))) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +
  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none') 

p
```

[image]

Then we do:

```r
p$layers[[2]]$position <- position_nudge(x = rep(c(-0.2, 0.2), each = 1024))
```

And now it looks like this:

```r
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to solve the problem using the method you taught me.